# Changing dropdown values with jQuery doesn't work with only one value

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu

I have a page with a number of dropdown boxes and some jQuery that will change the values of the proceeding dropdown menus based on the selection of the preceding dropdown box.

The code I have is here:

```
function changeDropDown(select, options) {
            var dropdown = $("select#" + select + "");
            dropdown.empty();    
            dropdown.load("changeDropdown.php?dd=" + select + "&id=" + $('#' + options + '').val());
            }
```

Then to call it I simply do this:

```
$('#pdi-Process').change(function() {
            changeDropDown('pdi-Condition','pdi-Process');
            });
```

This works and will change the options in the specified dropdown list based on the value of the option selected in the preceding dropdown menu.

My problem is that there is a chain of these dropdown menus and this code will only work if someone changes the value of a dropdown menu. Sometimes the option a user wants is the first one presented, or might be the only one available. In cases like these where the user cannot change the option, the code fails to work.

Using my years of experience in web development I have concluded the problem is probably due to .change() but what could I use to provide the same functionality but also allow it to work when the options cannot be changed? Is there an elegant way of doing this or shall I simply go with adding a blank option to every list so users can always change the values?

Answer (score 0):

Just trigger a change on the `.load()` callback :

```
dropdown.load("changeDropdown.php?dd=" + select + "&id=" + $('#' + options + '').val(), function(){
    dropdown.trigger('change');
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this does do what I want but comes with a slight issue. When a user selects an option from the first dropdown box, it will automatically select the default option for every proceeding dropdown box, which will then fire off the form submission event on the last dropdown box. This is obviously not desirable behaviour.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to help me. Instead of all the triggers firing at once now, it will only auto-select the next dropdown menu which is not ideal but better than having all of them firing at once. However it still doesn't solve my initial problem. If there is not more than one option to choose from, I cannot change the dropdown menu so the .change() trigger does not fire.

Comment: Alright, I think i finnaly understand. Here, try this solution : http://pastebin.com/fWzzsmd4 .

Comment: Oh wait, when you said "when the options cannot be changed", is it because you have 1 option or the `select` is disabled?

Comment: It's because I only have 1 option